# IE7 displays table headers differently

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have a table with headers and each header contains a span which have a background image that i use as a sperator between the th.

On all browsers it display as it should but on IE7 the seperator image (which is a span with background)
is showing on the bottom.

Good (IE8+,Chrome,FF):

[image]

Bad (IE7):

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="tableWrapper">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="sortable top-left-round"><a href="#" class="sortable">Lead Id</a><span></span></th>
                        <th class="sortable"><a href="#" class="sortable">Create Date</a><span></span></th>
                        <th class="sortable"><a href="#" class="sortable">Target Group</a><span></span></th>
                        <th class="sortable"><a href="#" class="sortable">Activity</a><span></span></th>
                        <th class="sortable"><a href="#" class="sortable">Type</a><span></span></th>
                        <th class="sortable"><a href="#" class="sortable">Last Update</a><span></span></th>
                        <th class="sortable"><a href="#" class="sortable">Close Date</a><span></span></th>
                        <th class="action_header_short top-right-round"><span>View</span></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="first">
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td class="col_name" title="Jackson">10/12/2011</td>
                        <td title="Jackson">Jackson</td>
                        <td title="Jackson">Jackson </td>
                        <td title="Jackson">Jackson</td>
                        <td title="Jackson">10/12/2011</td>
                        <td title="Jackson">10/12/2011</td>
                        <td class="action"><a href="#" class="view-btn"></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td class="col_name" title="Jackson">10/12/2011</td>
                        <td title="Jackson">Jackson</td>
                        <td title="Jackson">Jackson </td>
                        <td title="Jackson">Jackson</td>
                        <td title="Jackson">10/12/2011</td>
                        <td title="Jackson">10/12/2011</td>
                        <td class="action"><a href="#" class="view-btn"></a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <!-- end .tableWrapper -->
```

CSS:

```
table{
width: 890px;           
margin-left: 25px;  
border-collapse:collapse;
}
td{
border: 1px solid #99a3a7;
}
.top-left-round{
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 0px; 
}
.top-right-round{
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
}
table thead th{ 
    background: url(../images/table-header-bg.png) repeat-x;
    height: 42px;
    line-height: 40px;  
    border: 0px solid transparent;
    font-weight:normal; 
}
th.action_header span { 
    margin-right:50px;
}
th.action_header {
    width: 120px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 20px
}
th.action_header_short{
    padding-left: 20px;
}
th a.sortable,th.action_header span,th.action_header_short span {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
}
th a.sortable{
    padding: 0 15px;    
    background: url(../images/icons/arrow_dwn.png) right center no-repeat;
}
th.sortable span{   
    background: url(../images/cols-seperator.png) right top no-repeat;
    float:right;
    margin-right: -2px;
    width:5px;
    height: 42px;
}
th a:hover{
    color: #fff;
}

tbody td{
    padding: 0 5px; 
}

td.action{
    width:74px; 
    padding: 2px;
}

.tableWrapper{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just style the header with CSS? It seems pretty silly to be using an image with a background and some lines.

Comment: I took your advice and just styled it with simple css for IE7. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Style this with CSS instead of an image. You're always going to have issues using an image like this.